# How to configure properly VSCode for cucumber.js

Tags: gherkin, cucumberjs

I am learning cucumber.js with visual studio code.

In this test, all the steps are in error in the editor :
[image]

I tried a lot of things in my config, without success.

My current conf is

```
{
"gherkin-autocomplete.featuresPath": "features",
"cucumberautocomplete.steps": [
    "features/step_definitions/*.js",
],
"cucumberautocomplete.syncfeatures": "features/*feature",
```

}

And my folders in my project are organized like that :

[image]

What could be an ideal configuration in my case ?